# Export data from string

Tags: php, string, export, preg-replace, extract

I have following string:

```
{"id":3661917,"mId":2408699,"isR":false,"opps": [{"id":37794066,"optN":1,"wn":false,"rt":"1.24","fau":null},{"id":37794067,"optN":2,"wn":false,"rt":"1.01","fau":null},{"id":37794068,"optN":3,"wn":false,"rt":"5.40","fau":null},{"id":37794069,"optN":4,"wn":false,"rt":"3.36","fau":null},{"id":37794070,"optN":5,"wn":false,"rt":"11.40","fau":null}],"oTpId":7}
```

How can I get values: "optN" (for example "optN":1) and "rt" (for example "rt":"1.24")? I have no idea, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its `json` string, you can decode json string by `json_decode`, so use like

```
$json = '{"id":3661917,"mId":2408699,"isR":false,"opps": [{"id":37794066,"optN":1,"wn":false,"rt":"1.24","fau":null},{"id":37794067,"optN":2,"wn":false,"rt":"1.01","fau":null},{"id":37794068,"optN":3,"wn":false,"rt":"5.40","fau":null},{"id":37794069,"optN":4,"wn":false,"rt":"3.36","fau":null},{"id":37794070,"optN":5,"wn":false,"rt":"11.40","fau":null}],"oTpId":7}';
$json_array = json_decode($json,true);
if(isset($json_array['opps']) && $json_array['opps']!= false)
{
    foreach($json_array['opps'] as $jArray)
    {
        echo " optN = " .$jArray['optN'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo " rt = " .$jArray['rt'];
        echo "<br/>";echo "<br/>";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a JSON string. Simply decode this using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function and access to items as array. Example:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
echo $data['opps'][0]['optN']; // print first opps element optN value
echo $data['opps'][0]['rt']; // print first opps element rt value
```

Comment: Well, it's invalid JSON, technically.

Comment: @Will, I think question author simply wrong copied.

Answer (score 0):

This string is a [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/). You can convert it to a PHP object using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$your_string = '{"id":3661917,"mId":2408699,"isR":false,"opps": [{"id":37794066,"optN":1,"wn":false,"rt":"1.24","fau":null},{"id":37794067,"optN":2,"wn":false,"rt":"1.01","fau":null},{"id":37794068,"optN":3,"wn":false,"rt":"5.40","fau":null},{"id":37794069,"optN":4,"wn":false,"rt":"3.36","fau":null},{"id":37794070,"optN":5,"wn":false,"rt":"11.40","fau":null}],"oTpId":7}';
$object = json_decode( $your_string );
```